# Navigation bar background image - supporting iOS6 and iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, uinavigationbar

What is the best practice for selecting the correct navigation bar background image depending on the iOS version?

As I understand it, the image should be a height of 64px for iOS7 and 44px for iOS6.  Is it simply a matter of checking the iOS version running and then choosing the appropriate image (in an if statement)? Is there a way to do it in interface builder? Or better yet, is there a way to have iOS select the correct image automatically (based on the file name, etc.)?

Comment: The best answer I've found is to check the OS version and set the appropriate image.  It is to be noted that if you use a 44 px image on iOS 7 it may not be disastrous, depending on the style you use for the nav bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a different image for each version.  You check check for iOS 6 with

```
NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1
```

Apple alludes to this solution in their iOS7 transition guide

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html